# Compare one column to the next column over the entire worksheet using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a sheet of data, within which there are many adjacent columns that need to be compared
i.e.

- compare column A to column B,
- compare column C to column D,
- compare column E to column F, etc

If the data in the cell in the right hand column is higher than the data in the cell in the left hand column, I want the data in the cell in the right hand column to appear green.

So, for example, if cell A2="C", but the data in B2="D", then B2 would be green.

I can do this easily. But then, once I have got that condidtional formatting down in one column, I have to 'format paint' it to the next column (in this case, column D) to and then alter the forumla to get it to compare the cells in column D with the cells in column C.

Is there any forumla that I can enter that would always ensure that "the cells in this column get compared with the cells in the column immediately to the left", no matter which column I copied the conditional formatting (using format paint) into?

I have many sheets with many many columns, and it is taking me ages to alter the formula in each conditional formatting example!

Comment: Do you want to compare only constant entries ("10","C" etc), or formulae (=A1, =10) and constants?

Comment: The entries are static (i.e. not made using a formula) but I'll never know how many columns it applies to as each worksheet is different. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Ken,

I think that you are looking for this...

[image]

Try this. If you need more help, let me know.

What I did:
Put a letter in B2 and an other letter in C2, then created rule 1 in B2 as =B2>C3 and selected the format as green background. The in C2 as = B2

[image]

Comment: The last part of my text was overwritten by the second picture... It said. Copy B2 and C2 down and fill in the data (as paste values only)

Comment: Right, it seems I haven't been a member for lnog enough to post a picture of what I have so far, so I'll try and describe it.

In the "conditional Formatting" box, I have the rule 'Formula: =$E1<$D1'. The Format is 'Background=Green'. and 'Applies to' is "=$e:$E".

If I just take the '$' out of the 'Formula' portions, would this mean that I could just copy it across and it will always update itself to it's not location (column)?